# Create a table and insert data in one statement MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mamp

I'm trying to create a table and insert data into it in one statement but I can't figure out just how to do it.

The statement has to create a table that has 3 columns: stock symbol, price, and quote date.
The symbol data is supposed to be SELECT'ed from another table, my_stocks. The price and quote date need to be inserted manually.

I tried the following statement, but I keep getting a syntax error:

```
CREATE TABLE stock_prices (
    symbol VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    quote_date DATE NOT NULL,
    price DECIMAL(5,3) NOT NULL,
) SELECT symbol FROM my_stocks;
```

I'm running MySQL Community Server 5.5.28, btw.

Edit: I got it, the appropriate statement is:

```
CREATE TABLE stock_prices (
    quote_date DATE NOT NULL,
    price DECIMAL(5,5) NOT NULL
) SELECT `￼￼symbol`, SYSDATE() AS quote_date, 0 AS price FROM my_stocks;
```

Comment: remove comma and use below code

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE stock_prices (
    symbol VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    quote_date DATE NOT NULL,
    price DECIMAL(5,5) NOT NULL,
) SELECT symbol, now(), 0 FROM my_stocks;
```

Comment: Would be useful if you could explain the difference and why the original was incorrect.

Comment: I get this error when I try that: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') SELECT symbol, now(), 0 FROM my_stocks' at line 5